# Support of distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

How the support of Dirac distribution is $\{0\}$.
I have started reading Distributions just a few days before.
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that you understand that $\delta(x)$ is defined to be $0$ whenever $x$ is not $0$, there's really no question here.

Comment: @BrianBorchers well, $\delta$ is a distribution and not a function and hence is not even defined pointwise. The definition of support for distributions is different than that for functions so the question is actually an exercise that is less trivial than your comment would suggest.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the support of a distribution? If so, where are you stuck in your proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that a distribution $T$ vanishes on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if for every $\phi  \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \phi \subseteq U$ we have $T(\phi) = 0$. The support of a distribution $\operatorname{supp} T$ is defined as the complement of the largest open set on which $T$ vanishes.

Now consider the Dirac distribution $\delta_0$. For the open set $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \phi \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ we clearly have $\delta_0(\phi) = \phi(0) = 0$. Clearly $\delta_0$ does not vanish on $\mathbb{R}$ so $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is the largest open set which $\delta_0$ vanishes on.

It follows $\operatorname{supp} \delta_0 = \{0\}$.